# Python command-line Tic Tac Toe for two humans

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, tic-tac-toe

I’d love some feedback on this human v. human, tic tac toe game I wrote in Python 2.7.10. I’d love to hear your thoughts on optimization and making the code simpler and more “pythonic”.

Also, I’m wondering if passing the `player` and `turn` variables around the way I have is the best approach, or if I should consider global variables (which is how I might do it in Javascript, in a closure).

```
# Command-line Tic Tac Toe for two humans written in Python.
# Play in a terminal by running 'python tictactoe.py'.

boxes = [ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ]
first_player = 'X'
turn = 1
winning_combos = [  [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6],
                    [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6], ]

def print_board(initial=False):
    """ Print the game board. If this is the beginning of the game,
        print out 1-9 in the boxes to show players how to pick a
        box. Otherwise, update each box with X or 0 from boxes[].
    """
    print('''
             {} | {} | {} 
            -----------
             {} | {} | {}
            -----------
             {} | {} | {} 
        ''').format(*([x for x in range(1, 10)] if initial else boxes))

def take_turn(player, turn):
    """ Create a loop that keeps asking the current player for
        their input until a valid choice is made.
    """
    while True:
        box = raw_input('Player %s, type a number from 1-9 to select a box: ' % player)

        try:
            box = int(box) - 1 # subtract 1 to sync with boxes[] index numbers
            if 0 <= box <= 8:
                if boxes[box] == ' ': # initial value
                    boxes[box] = player # set to value of current player
                    break
                else:
                    print('That box is already marked, try again.\n')
                    continue
            else:
                print('That number is out of range, try again.\n')
                continue

        except ValueError:
            # Not an integer
            print('That\'s not a valid number, try again.\n')
            continue

def switch_player(turn):
    """ Switch the player based on how many moves have been made.
        X starts the game so if this turn # is even, it's 0's turn. 
    """
    current_player = '0' if turn % 2 == 0 else 'X'
    return current_player

def check_for_win(player, turn):
    """ Check for a win (or a tie). For each combo in winning_combos[],
        count how many of its corresponding squares have the current 
        player's mark. If a player's score count reaches 3, return a win.
        If it doesn't, and this is already turn # 9, return a tie. If
        neither, return False so the game continues.
    """
    win = False
    tie = False
    if turn > 4: # need at least 5 moves before a win is possible
        for x in range(len(winning_combos)):
            score = 0
            for y in range(len(winning_combos[x])):
                if boxes[winning_combos[x][y]] == player:
                    score += 1
                if score == 3:
                    win = True

        if turn == 9:
            tie = True

    return win, tie

def play(player, turn):
    """ Create a loop that keeps the game in play
        until it ends in a win or tie
    """
    while True:
        take_turn(player, turn)
        print_board()
        win, tie = check_for_win(player, turn)
        if win or tie:
            if win:
                print('Game over. %s wins!\n' % player)
            else:
                print('Game over. It\'s a tie.\n')
            break
        turn += 1
        player = switch_player(turn)

# Begin the game: 
print('\n\nWelcome to Tic Tac Toe for two humans!')
print_board(initial=True)
play(first_player, turn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid too much code in `try` blocks

The `try ... except ValueError` in the `take_turn` function wraps too many statements that it shouldn't need. Only the `int(...)` statement may raise a `ValueError` there, so it would be better to wrap only that in the `try`. When you wrap a large block of code, it can lead to masked errors or make defect localization harder.

#### Magic values

Instead of referring to the player symbols by their literals like `'0'` and `'X'`, it would be better to give them names.

#### Iterate over elements when possible

In this code you iterate over indexes of elements:

```
   for x in range(len(winning_combos)):
        score = 0
        for y in range(len(winning_combos[x])):
            if boxes[winning_combos[x][y]] == player:
                score += 1
            if score == 3:
                win = True
```

It would be more natural, simpler and safer to iterate over elements:

```
for combo in winning_combos:
    score = 0
    for index in combo:
        if boxes[index] == player:
            # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. That makes sense about `try ... except` and yes, that iteration is much more obvious and simpler. Mine is lifted from a javascript mindset, I see now.

Answer (score 1):

If I could make one suggestion, it would be to tab in everything one more level and make it a class. This gives you the ability to call the program from the command line, using `if __name__ == "__main__"` but also load it as a module in the interpreter and play around with it as a malleable component. With as little overhead as python has in making a class vs a collection of functions, I've found very little reason not to start out with constructing a class right off the bat.